# Allowing any ASCII character transmitted in string with xmlrpc

Tags: python, encoding, xml-rpc

I am using xmlrpc to send a string of characters (arbitrary 8-bit character) from a server to a client. As it turns out, the carriage-return character `\r` (dec `13` hex 0xd) gets suppressed. That is, when the original string consists of the following three characters (represented by their hex-code):

```
0x3a 0xd 0xa
```

then I receive on the client side only 'two' characters:

```
0x3a 0xa
```

How can I configure xmlrpc (in python) so I am able to receive the full, original 3-characters string with `0xd`? Is there a way this can be done without using a binary wrapper or something else?

Comment: They are both valid line separators depending on os, and can be converted easily to one or the other, why is this a problem?

Comment: `\r` is the carriage **R**eturn character. `\n` is the **N**ewline character. Anyway, could you show a minimal example of the problem and expected output?

Comment: You do not seem to understand my problem. On the server side the sequence `0x3a 0xd 0xa` should be send through xmlrpc to a client side, and I want to receive the exact same sequence, that is `0x3a 0xd 0xa` (these are the hex-representations of the three characters sent through xmlrpc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass an str object as a string value in XML-RPC, it is encoded and decoded as a string. (BTW, that string should consist of characters allowed in XML, though that is not important in your case.) It is not a binary block, and `\r\n` is translated to `\n` when XML is parsed. IMHO, nothing can be done, and no set of options saves the situation.

Just see what `dumps()` and `loads()` from `xmlrpclib` do to your string:

```
>>> from xmlrpclib import dumps, loads
>>> s = '\x3a\x0d\x0a'
>>> e = dumps((s,)) # Just a tuple
>>> e
'<params>\n<param>\n<value><string>:\r\n</string></value>\n</param>\n</params>\n'
>>> loads(e)
((':\n',), None)
```

So, when `loads()` is performed, the `\r\n` sequence is translated to `\n`, and `\r` is lost. You may, of course, use a transformed string (e.g. `s.encode('hex')` looks quite nice), but, as far as I understand, if you can not alter server behavior (to perform `s.decode('hex')` on the parameter), nothing can help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Seems I have some coding work to do on the server and client side.

Answer (score 0):

As an update for python3, use xmlrpc.client in stead of xmlrpclib:

```
>>> from xmlrpc.client import dumps, loads
```

Comment: Useful update, although this should be an Edit on the previous answer.